# Regarding interrupt based communication

Tags: communication, arm, interrupt, pic, i2c

We have a simple architecture :

1. Main chip (arm9 based)
2. PIC controller

The PIC communicates to ARM via an interrupt based I2C communication protocol for transfer of data. Inside the interrupt we signal a task which reads the data from the I2C layer (bus).

In case the data is limited we usually won't have much problem to read the data and send it to upper layer. In case this data is very huge the interrupt will be tied for a long time.

The first question is:

1. Am I right?
2. In case I am right, how to avoid the same? ...or can we a different solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have some kind of 'worker thread', sometimes called a kernel thread, whose job it is to pull data out of the I2C interface and buffer it, hand it off to other parts of your system, etc.  Use the interrupt routine only to un-block the kernel thread. That way, if there are other duties the system has to perform, it is not prevented from doing so by the interrupt handler, and you still get your data in from your device in a timely manner.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't read a complete packet in one execution of the interrupt routine. Depending on the hardware support you should handle one sample/bit/byte, store data in a buffer and only signal the task when the packet is complete.